# GLSL gl_VertexID is not incrementing

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glew

I'm currently in the process of making a 2D Game Engine in C++ with GLEW and GLFW!
At the moment I'm working on sprites and ways to render them. I want to be able to resize them as I need it, but strangely my attempt does not work out. My way of realising that, is to simply create a VBO with 6 vertices which all have (0, 0) as the position. And then I'd resize and set their position with the vertex shader.

**VertexShader.vert:**

```
#version 140

in vec2 vertPos;
in vec2 vertUV;

out vec2 fragPos;
out vec2 fragUV;

uniform vec2 position;
uniform vec2 size;

void main(){
    //POSITION
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;

    gl_Position.x = position.x*2 - 1;
    gl_Position.y = position.y*2 - 1;

    //SIZE
    switch(gl_VertexID){
        case 1: gl_Position.x += size.x; break;
        case 5: gl_Position.x += size.x; break;

        case 2: gl_Position.y += size.y; break;
        case 3: gl_Position.y += size.y; break;

        case 4: gl_Position.x += size.x; gl_Position.y += size.y; break;
    }

    fragPos = vertPos;
    fragUV = vec2(vertUV.x, 1.0 - vertUV.y); 
}
```

But this does, strangely, not work how I expected. It does not show anything.
When I add vertPos to glPosition like so:

```
gl_Position.x = vertPos.x + position.x*2 - 1;
gl_Position.y = vertPos.y + position.y*2 - 1;
```

And also create the VBO with some starting "shape" it looks like 
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIKY8.png).
I really have no clue why my attemp does not work out.

Comment: It can be a shader compilation error if it doesn't show anything. Are you using `glGetShaderInfoLog` function after you compile the shader?

Comment: No, it's definitely no shader error. Just as I described: When I add "vertPos.x/.y" to the gl_Position, then it does show something. Not the right thing, but still.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe the problem occurs because you are multiplying **float** by **int** here: `gl_Position.x = vertPos.x + position.x*2 - 1;`. I think that `position` is something between  0 and 1 and when you multiply that by an _int_ you can get weird results. Maybe change the ints to floats: `gl_Position.x = vertPos.x + position.x*2.0 - 1.0;`

Comment: You've probably pushed everything outside of clip-space. We've no idea what the magnitude of values you are using for `size` are. If the end result of this math is `x` or `y` being greater than `w` or less than `-w` (where `w` is **1.0** in this case), the vertex is in a position outside your viewing volume. All vertices may be outside your viewing volume, in which case nothing will be shown. Likewise, the values used may cause polygon winding order to reverse and then you can run into culling issues on geometry that IS within the viewing volume.

Comment: @MarGenDo I see what you mean, but sadly it's not the problem.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman I made sure it's not. My values are `Pos:[0.138889, 0.222222] Size:[0.986111, 0.555556]`

Comment: Whats strange is, even when I add something odd to the vertex shader like `if(gl_VertexID == 3) gl_Position.x += 0.5;` nothing changes. It still shows the red small box.

Comment: With further testing I found out that position works fine. It's only the size that makes problems.

Comment: Yeah, well 0.138889 + 0.986111 = 1.125, so even before any floating-point rounding, you're already outside the viewing volume.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yea, some vertices. But if you look at the shader, the first vertex is at `position`. And some others are inside too.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that gl_vertexID does not work. It is always 0.

Comment: It definitely works, even if you are not doing indexed rendering the vertex ID is implicitly generated when you make calls like `glDrawArrays (...)`. You would have to be doing immediate mode rendering for it not to work and even then, I think implementations will wind up tagging immediate vertices with an ID.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Even if I change it to something like  [that](http://pastebin.com/8rLZx0CR) . It has no effect. My small red box does not change in any way.

Comment: It's pretty messy here. Would it be a big of a problem to move this conversation to a chat platform like google hangouts or something? I'd be pretty happy if you could do that. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Let us help you here for now. Could you please post your fragment shader, code for setting uniforms and `glDrawArrays` call?

Comment: The "problem" is that I have all these different functions splittet in different classes. I tried anyway to visualize it. [fragment shader](http://pastebin.com/4X79Jhiy) [c++ code](http://pastebin.com/AJrTM2g6)

Comment: [If something is still unclear](https://github.com/Kiryu144/AmethystReworked/tree/master/source)

Comment: @MarGenDo I should have linked to you.. My bad.

Comment: If you want to find out, if the Vertex_ID is working correctly, you should draw two triangles filling the whole screen and visualise the ID with colors.

If you think the id is between 0..6, than you should set "fragColor = vec3(1.0f) / 6 * gl_VertexID"